# Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-media-compat' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

I have added List of plugins in my flutter app

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  connectivity:
  rxdart:
  validate: ^1.7.0
  image_picker: ^0.4.10
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.2"
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.2+1
  google_sign_in:
```

> Dart & Flutter version : Dart 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

This is my android app - gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.standardappstructure"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Destribution Gradle version :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Project level : gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I am changing gradle classpath to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Its showing me

> Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Comment: What is your `buildToolsVersion`? Can't find a declaration of it in the `app` `gradle`.

Comment: As default i didn't added buildToolsVersion but i tried with buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' and '27.1.1'    but still same error.

Answer (score 2):

I added `implementation("com.android.support:support-v4:latest_version_number")` to my build.gradle and it worked.Hope this helps.

Comment: I used implementation("com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0") and it worked thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this error with below code change in android>build.gradle

If your project config with kotlin then

```
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'

     replace with new version

   ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
```

and

```
dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'}
                    replace with new version
dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'}
```

You  probably get your obstacles if your exception is

What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
 Android dependency 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Comment: For a newer version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` check https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

Answer (score 1):

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3
firebase_auth: ^0.6.5
image_picker: 0.4.0
```

This works for me